# Angular2 Observable scoping issues

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I thought I understood javascript scoping but I'm thinking I must be off somewhere...

I create an observable (for a session timeout type feature) which decrements a number and emits each second. I can subscribe to this fine and see the data changing great. My issue is that sometimes events outside of the Observer will "reset" the timer; however, the values used inside the observer do not reflect this reset.

I had thought that by using fat arrow syntax `this` would be preserved, but apparently I'm incorrect somewhere.

The observable is created in the constructor which is injected as a singleton into a module.

```
@Injectable()
export class TimeoutService {

  private _internalTimer: number;    
  private _logoutThreshold: number;
  private _timer$: Observable<number>;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {

    this._logoutThreshold = 3000;

    document.onkeypress = this.resetTimer;

    this._internalTimer = this._logoutThreshold;    

    this._timer$ = new Observable(observer => {

      observer.next(this._internalTimer)

      setInterval(() => {
        this._internalTimer--;
        console.log("timer in observer", this._internalTimer);
        observer.next(this._internalTimer);
      }, 1000);

    });
  }

  resetTimer() {
    this._internalTimer = this._logoutThreshold;
    console.log("timer in reset", this._internalTimer);
  }    
}
```

In this example the "timer in observer" works great, starting at 3000 and counting down every second; however, the "timer in reset" is always undefined. This is doubly confusing since I would think at weirdest case it would just be a constant 3000 since I assign it in the constructor outside of the Observable.

How can I ensure that I'm always in the same scope in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah and as per normal within minutes of posting the question I solved it. Turns out I did understand the scoping in fat arrow correctly, just wasn't using it on the document listeners.

Changing

```
document.onkeypress = this.resetTimer;
```

to

```
document.onkeypress = e => this.resetTimer();
```

makes everything work perfectly!